# Como Atualizar 2 tabelas com Switch case e dados do banco de dados e outros vindos de um retorno xml?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Progredi bastante no código, dentro do que achava necessário, só que não sei como organizar a minha sintaxe para que ocorra tudo como quero, o *switch/case* que corre no banco pra ver qual id ta cadastrado e pegue o valor no *switch* e passe para a outra tabela no update... esta ocorrendo algum erro alguém poderia ajudar?

```
<?php

require_once("core/config/config.php");

if (isset($_POST['notificationType']) && $_POST['notificationType'] == 'transaction') {

    //CÓDIGO DA NOTIFICAÇÃO
    $code = $_POST['notificationCode'];

    //MONTAMOS A URL PARA PEGAR O STATUS
    $url = 'https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/transactions/notifications/' . $code . '?email=' . $email . '&token=' . $token;

    //PEGAMOS O STATUS VIA CURL
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $transaction= curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    //SE DER ALGUM ERRO NO NOSSO CURL VAI VIM COMO Unauthorized
    if($transaction == 'Unauthorized'){


        exit;//Mantenha essa linha
    }

    $pdo = conectaDB();
                    $get = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pagseguro");
                    $get->execute();

                    $query = $get->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    foreach ($query as $row) {
                            $user =   $row['id_user'];
                            $codigo_transacao = $row['id_transacao'];
                            $codigo = $row['packed'];
                    }


    $entregue = 'S';

    switch ($query->$codigo) {
        case '1':
            $chips = '30.00';
            break;

        case '2':
            $chips = '50.00';
            break;

        case '3':
            $chips = '100.00';
            break;

        case '4':
            $chips = '250.00';
            break;
        }

    //COMVERTE O RERTORNO EM STRING
    $transaction = simplexml_load_string($transaction);       

    /*
     * STATUS RETORNO         
     * 1 - Aguardando pagamento
     * 2 - Em análise
     * 3 - Paga
     * 4 - Disponível
     * 5 - Em disputa
     * 6 - Devolvida
     * 7 - Cancelada
     */ 

    //PEGAMOS O CÓDIGO DO STATUS
    switch ($transaction->status) {
        case '1':
            $status = 'Aguardando pagamento';
            break;

        case '2':
            $status = 'Em análise';
            break;

        case '3':
            $status = 'Paga';
            $edit2   = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE pagseguro SET entregue=:entregue WHERE id_transacao=:id_transacao");
            $edit2->bindValue(':entregue', $entregue);           
            $edit2->bindValue(':id_transacao', $transaction->code);
            $edit2->execute();

           // SECOND CASE
            $update   = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET credits=:credits WHERE username=:user_pagseguro");
            $update->bindValue(':credits', $chips);           
            $update->bindValue(':user_pagseguro', $user);
            $update->execute();
            break;

        case '4':
            $status = 'Disponível';
            break;

        case '5':
            $status = 'Em disputa';
            break;

        case '6':
            $status = 'Devolvida';
            break;

        case '7':
            $status = 'Cancelada';
            break;                      
    }

    //ATUALIZAMOS O STATUS NO BANCO DADOS.
    $pdo    = conectaDB();
    $edit   = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE pagseguro SET status=:status WHERE id_transacao=:id_transacao");
    $edit->bindValue(':status', $status);           
    $edit->bindValue(':id_transacao', $transaction->code);

    $edit->execute();           
}   
?>
```

exemplo de um pedaco do meu banco na parte q tem a trasacao o pacote e o id do usuario...

> ```
> ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> |   id_user        |   codigo_transacao        |   packed |
> ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> |   Joaozinho   |   2asd654asd65as4c           |   1      |
> ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> |   Mariazinha  |   1asd654as123214d           |   2      |
> ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> |   Carlinhos   |   4asd654asd65as4dasd2       |   4      |
> ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> ```

Comment: ATUALIZADO O CODIGO :

Comment: @diegofm mas no caso preciso fazer mais de 2 ações exemplo, atualizar a tabela atual e atualizar outra tabela do banco quando estiver ok o pagamento... no caso a logica da programação ta correta né?